# How to send form data in Postman

Tags: json, spring-boot, postman, dto, form-data

I'm trying to send a JSON object along with a file from my Rest CLIENT(POSTMAN), I'm using postman to do this job, I selected form-data and after entering all the information when i try to submit the information - This error comes up

"timestamp": 1547055355293,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------903236456380875456491477;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/test"

I have tried setting header to multipart/form-data but it did not work. I cannot receive any DTO

Comment: instead, use Application/json?

Comment: Try to use Application/json ? but what is the consumes type of your rest endpoint ?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/submitPostDetails",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
 public String submitPostDetails(@RequestBody SubmitPostDetailsDto submitPostDetailsDto,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)

Comment: This is the end point that I'm trying to hit